# Pixelmator Export Script for Various Sizes

Tags: android, ios

Has anyone found a way to script the process of exporting different image sizes from Pixelmator? Ideally I would like to take a 1024x1024 .pxm image and export it to the various ios and android app icon sizes in the .png format.  I have experimented with using java/groovy to take a 1024x1024 .png file and resize it, but the quality isn't always great.

Answer (score 1):

None that I am aware of directly from Pixelmator; however you can export your 1024x1024 image, and then use sites like makeappicon.com or iconswitch.com to generate all app icon sizes in PNG format.

Pixelmator Templates has a tutorial on this: http://www.pixelmatortemplates.com/how-to-edit-one-of-our-templates/